# Change CSS font with JS/JQuery and dropdown box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use

```
<select>
```

in order to change the font of 4 various paragraphs and headers. This is what I tried

```js
var text = document.getElementById("text");
var text2 = document.getElementById("text2");
var text3 = document.getElementById("text3");
var text4 = document.getElementById("text4");


$("#btn_font").on('click', function() {
  var font = document.getElementById("font");
  text.style.fontFamily = String(font);
  text2.style.fontFamily = String(font);
  text3.style.fontFamily = String(font);
  text4.style.fontFamily = String(font);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="font">
  <option value="">Default</option>
  <option value="arial">Arial</option>
  <option value="helvetica">Helvetica</option>
  <option value="times new roman">Times New Roman</option>
  <option value="times">Times</option>
  <option value="courier new">Courier New</option>
  <option value="courier">Courier</option>
  <option value="verdana">Verdana</option>
  <option value="georgia">Georgia</option>
  <option value="palatino">Palatino</option>
  <option value="garamond">Garamond</option>
  <option value="bookman">Bookman</option>
  <option value="comic sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
  <option value="trebuchet MS">Trebuchet MS</option>
  <option value="arial black">Arial Black</option>
  <option value="impact">Impact</option>
</select>
<button id="btn_font">Update</button>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `String(font)` ?  If you are trying to get the value of the select then that's just `font.value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You no need to convert to string the variable **font**. font is javascript object so you should get element value using **.value**

```
var font = document.getElementById("font");
text.style.fontFamily = font.value
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be replacing `String(font);` with `String(font.value);` or just `font.value;`

Answer (score 0):

Several issues

- Use jQuery if you already have jQuery, otherwise add .value to make the script work - the String() is not needed `var font = document.getElementById("font").value;`
- use .val() to get the value in jQuery
- Use a class
- type="button"

```js
$("#btn_font").on('click', function() {
  var font = $("#font").val();
  $(".text").css({"font-family":font}); // updates all in one line
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="font">
  <option value="">Default</option>
  <option value="arial">Arial</option>
  <option value="helvetica">Helvetica</option>
  <option value="times new roman">Times New Roman</option>
  <option value="times">Times</option>
  <option value="courier new">Courier New</option>
  <option value="courier">Courier</option>
  <option value="verdana">Verdana</option>
  <option value="georgia">Georgia</option>
  <option value="palatino">Palatino</option>
  <option value="garamond">Garamond</option>
  <option value="bookman">Bookman</option>
  <option value="comic sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
  <option value="trebuchet MS">Trebuchet MS</option>
  <option value="arial black">Arial Black</option>
  <option value="impact">Impact</option>
</select>
<button type="button" id="btn_font">Update</button>
<div class="text" id="text1">Div 1</div>
<div class="text" id="text2">Div 2</div>
<div class="text" id="text3">Div 3</div>
<div class="text" id="text4">Div 4</div>
```